# Symfony preg_match a route

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I need to preg_match my route, i try like this :

```
if (preg_match('surveillance', $request->headers->get('referer'))){
     var_dump("match");
} else {
     var_dump("dont match");
}
```

With my headers get referer i get :

```
http://.../surveillance/item/veille/h/55
```

and i would like get return "match" if i have "surveillance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add delimiters to preg_match expression.

```
if (preg_match('/surveillance/', $request->headers->get('referer'))){
     var_dump("match");
} else {
     var_dump("dont match");
}
```

**OR**

```
if (stristr($request->headers->get('referer'),'surveillance')){
      var_dump("match");
} else {
     var_dump("dont match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not the answer you are looking for but instead of parsing the referer with a regex you should probably use separate controller actions and routes or just use the same route/controller but using a route parameter.

That is what they are made for.

Answer (score 0):

Your search string is not variable and you are not concerned with its location in the header string, so regex is not the best method for your case.

Just use `strpos()` like this:

```
if (strpos($request->headers->get('referer'),'surveillance')!==false){
     var_dump("match");
} else {
     var_dump("dont match");
}
```

But the above will match `surveillance` ANYWHERE in the header string.  If you want to try to check that the full string `surveillance` is being used as a directory value, you could wrap it in slashes (`/`):

```
if (strpos($request->headers->get('referer'),'/surveillance/')!==false){
     var_dump("match");
} else {
     var_dump("dont match");
}
```

I don't know about Symfony, so Mawcel might be right on in his/her post.

Beyond these options, if you want to be really sure that `surveillance` is being used as a valid/existing directory on your server, then you'll have to look into other functions that check if the directory exists.  If this isn't on your server, then you might want to look into a more refined regex pattern that checks the substring location.